# How to exclude a row from filtering when using global filter in angular primeng table?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have one row with unique identifier. I want to exclude it from filtering when user tries to search or filter the table. That means it should be always visible.

Comment: cant you write your own filter logic ??

Comment: you can remove the default table filter and write a custom filter

Comment: actually I am new to primeng. and didn't try primeng custom filter. can you provide me one useful link to follow with?